# Vim delete up to X character

Tags: vim

So I am trying to find the quickest way to delete up to the last period. My cursor would be on the first period, so I want to delete from the first period to the last one. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
#{customer.OrderHeader[0].BillingAddress[0].Line1}
```

Answer (score 1):

First try: You can `dt.` and repeat the command once more by `.`.

You might also try [JumpToLastOccurrence plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3386)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to press `.` to repeat `dt.` many times,

E.g. there are 20 dots in the line. You can do:

```
v$F.hd
```

Answer (score 0):

With cursor in place on the first period, type `d/.*\(\.\)\@=`

This should yield:

```
#{customer.Line1}
```

This uses lookahead to look from current cursor position up to any character followed by a period, but does not consume the final period.

Perhaps consider recording with `q` to make it easy to access as a macro.

Comment: Not your original question, but more generally, you could use `:s/\..*\(\.\)\@=//` to avoid having to fiddle around with cursor position.